# Fatal error: Call to a member function url() on a non-object on line 8

Tags: php, foreach, kirby

I am new to PHP, currently getting error saying

> Fatal error: Call to a member function url() on a non-object on line 8

Below is the code I am trying

```
<?php
   $subpages = $site->pages()->children()->visible();
   $image_url = $subpages->image()->url();
   $title = $subpage->title()->text();

   foreach($subpages as $subpage) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
      echo '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>';
      echo '<a href="' . $subpage->url() . '" title="' . $title . '">';
      echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="' . $title . '" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">';
      echo '</a>';
      echo '</div>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: You cannot use objects like this. Check how to use objects and its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code corrected:

```
<?php
   $subpages = $site->children()->visible();
   foreach($subpages as $subpage) {
   $image_url = $subpage->image()->url();
   $title = $subpage->title()->html();
      echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
      echo '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>';
      echo '<a href="' . $subpage->url() . '" title="' . $title . '">';
      echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="' . $title . '" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">';
      echo '</a>';
      echo '</div>';
   }
?>
```

What's wrong with your code:

- You should use `$site->children()` to list all children of the site
  [See kirby docs](https://getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet/site/children)
- You're defining `$image_url` and `$title` before the foreach which is not correct. I moved them just at the beginning of the foreach
  loop. Also corrected image_url to use subpage instead of subpages.
- You're using `text()` on your title. That doesn't exist, use either `kirbytext()` or `html()` depending on what you want to do. See the
  docs.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what are the values and methods in $subpages? i think there is problem when you assigning the values to the variable.